# How to remove unused strange element from site?

Tags: css, wordpress, styling, box

i have one little issue that cant resolve myself. I want to remove second box (at bottom) in this [page](http://definitiv.cz/joining-2/) but when inspect CSS found that both elements are defined as :

```
<pre></pre>
```

so dont know how to handle that box, and remove it. Form in that page are generated by "User registration & user profile – Profile Builder plugin".

[image]

Comment: `.remove()` is the droid you're looking for

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: How you meen? I dont understand you well. Can you explain?

smilebomb read first post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Follow the link in Rob's comment. How do you want to remove this element? With javascript? Jquery? Can you edit the template, i.e. the `html` directly?

Comment: Yes i want to remove that field. I can modify HTML but dont know from where is generated that box. Is possible to remove via JS or JQ?

Answer (score 1):

in your css:

```
:css selector { 
  display:none;
}
```

you also can declare in html:

```
<pre style="display:none;"> </pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. was usefull to identify from where is comming issue. I resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your javascript file, or add it in `<script></script>` in your `<head>`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[1].remove()
```

You also have `jquery` on the site without the traditional `$` alias, so you can also do:

```
jquery('pre').eq(1).remove();
```